# How do I make my background fixed in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, background, fixed

How do I make my background fixed, so it will not scroll, in this particular code?

I already tried body.setAttribute("backgroundAttachment", "fixed");, but it didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script>
<!-- Activate cloaking device
var randnum = Math.random();
var inum = 5;
// Change this number to the number of images you are using.
var rand1 = Math.round(randnum * (inum-1)) + 1;
images = new Array
images[1] = "bf1.jpg"
images[2] = "fifa17.jpg"
images[3] = "rocketleague.jpg"
images[4] = "civ6.jpg"
images[5] = "infinitewarfare.png"
// Ensure you have an array item for every image you are using.
var image = images[rand1]
// Deactivate cloaking device -->
</script>  
</head>

<body>
<script>
<!-- Activate cloaking device
//document.write('<body background="' + image + '" text="white">');document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed"; 
var body=document.querySelector("body");
body.setAttribute("background", image);
body.setAttribute("text", "white");
body.setAttribute("backgroundAttachment", "fixed");
// Deactivate cloaking device -->
</script>
<img src="RANDOM-IMAGE-TO-MAKE-IT-POSSIBLE-TO-SCROLL.png" style="position:absolute; opacity:0.5; TOP:122px; LEFT:140px; width: 1000px; height: 1400px; object-fit: cover;" align="middle">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [css_positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Why downvotes? Its just a question

Comment: @KevinKloet I can't get it to work in this code

Comment: Your code has lots of errors in it, please create a code snippet or a jsfiddle with the correct code.

Comment: @Spykee I changed the post. I didn't know how to post html code.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this question as solved. To do that, please click on the tick mark adjacent to the answer that you found most helpful, so that it turns green. We do not edit titles to add [solved] tags here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final answer by Igor**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script>
var images=["bf1.jpg","fifa17.jpg","rocketleague.jpg","civ6.jpg","infinitewarfare.png"];
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)}
</script>
</head><body>
123
<script>
document.body.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url("+ images[getRandomArbitrary(0,5)] +"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center top; background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover;  width: ; display: ;   color: red;")/*from 0 to 4*/;
</script>
</body></html>
```